# How to create a vertical table

Tags: theming, 9

Can anyone please help me to render theme_table data in vertical format instead of horizontal format ?
Currently horizontal table is overflowing the page and breaking breaking points.

My current code :

```
    $build['table'] = [
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#empty' => $this->t('No content has been found.'),
    ];

    return $build;
```

It generates following table but I wanted it in vertical table format.Where header is in left and row is in right instead of header in top and rows at bottom.

I am using **Drupal 9.3.9 with Bartik** theme.

I can think of a way where I can process array of header and rows and format it to render in vertical format. Before proceeding to that I am searching if we have any core functions which can provide the same functionality. As It would not be efficient to completely rewrite array data.

[image: Horizontal table Overflow]

Comment: Drupal does not really care what data and how many cells you put into rows.... if you want multiple rows instead of cells, provide the corresponing data structure with multiple `$rows` instead of just one.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly Drupal core does not provide responsive tables.

You'll need to use contrib or custom library solution to solve this issue.

Have a look at these contribs:

**[Responsive Tables Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables_filter)**

[image]

**[Simple Responsive Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_responsive_table)**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately it is not what i am looking for. I am mainly looking for a way Where header is in left and row is in right instead of header in top and rows at bottom using core functions if any exists.

Comment: @miststudent2011 To my knowledge, there is no such core function. Another possibility could be to copy core's [table.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21table.html.twig/9.3.x) into your theme and adjust as you like. You could make them `<divs>` instead of `<table>`, and theme it with CSS to look like a table.

Comment: @miststudent2011 Since you control the code, I guess if you go the `<div>`s route, you might as well [create your own custom template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module) rather than using `'#type' => 'table',`.

Comment: @miststudent2011 this is all just CSS - Drupal’s included themes don’t have any styles for alternative table layouts so you’ll have to find/provide your own if you still want to use tables. Or create your own markup/styles to fit exactly what you need as suggested. Or take a step back and see if `word-wrap: ellipsis` doesn’t cover your needs. Drupal won’t help you here as this is fundamentally a styling issue